# (SOLVED) Calculus Integration $\int_1^2 \frac{2}{((x^2)(x+1))}dx $, where's my mistake?

Tags: calculus

Integrate (upper limit =2, lower limit = 1)

$\int_1^2 \frac{2}{((x^2)(x+1))}dx $

My ans: $1+2\ln(3/2)$

Lecturer ans: $1+2\ln(3/4)$

Checked multiple times, can't find out where's the careless mistake (if any)

PLEASE HELP!

Comment: We can not find the mistake if you did not provide your proof !

Comment: What are your steps? What is your partial fraction decomposition?

Comment: In Mathematica says that $\int_1^2 \frac{x}{x^2 (x+1)} \, dx = Log[4/3]$, So, you wrote wrong the equation, because none is right.

Comment: SOrry i edited. it should be 2 instead of x

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Via partial fraction decomposition, we can break this integral as: $$\begin{align}\int_1^2 \frac{2}{x^2(x+1)}dx & = 2\int_1^2 \frac{dx}{x^2(x+1)} \\ & = 2\int_1^2\left[-\frac{1}{x} + \frac{1}{x^2} + \frac{1}{x+1}\right]dx \\ & = 2\left[-\ln|x| - \frac{1}{x}  + \ln|x+1|\right]_1^2 \\ & = 2\left[\ln\left|\frac{x+1}{x}\right| - \frac{1}{x}\right]_1^2 \\ & = 2\left[\ln\left|\frac{3}{2}\right| - \frac{1}{2} - \ln|2| - (-1)\right]\\ & = 2\left[\ln\left(\frac{3}{4}\right) + \frac{1}{2}\right] \\ & = 2\ln\left(\frac{3}{4}\right) + 1\end{align}$$

Comment: Now edited to reflect the new question.

Comment: Thanks @pyrazolam I was wrong when doing partial fraction and i din't know it's was wrong. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Even without doing the integration, it's possible to see that the answer $1+2\ln(3/2)$ cannot be correct:  Because of the $x+1$ in the numerator, the integrand $2/(x^2(x+1))$ is *less than* $1$ for $x\gt1$, so the integral from $x=1$ to $2$ (an interval of length $1$) is less than $1$.  But $3/2\gt1$ implies $\ln(3/2)\gt0$, which makes the purported answer greater than $1$.

This doesn't mean that $1+2\ln(3/4)$ is necessarily correct, but at least $\ln(3/4)\lt0$ means $1+2\ln(3/4)\lt1$.